# Methods not working with tester in java

Tags: java, methods

I'm a newbie coder here currently taking a computer science class based on java.  I'm having issues with a program I'm supposed to be writing and I can't seem to figure it out regardless of what I look up, so I'm asking on here.

The instructions say: Create a class.  Create a method within the class called `printDimensions()` that displays the dimensions of a letter-size(8.5x11 inches) sheet of paper in millimeters.  There are 25.4 millimeters per inch (constant value). Use constants and comments in the method.  It also says (make use of printf to limit the number of decimal places in your method.

As of right now I am stuck in the middle of using the print statement and the return value for the method.  I also have a tester that I am using to test the code, but I'm getting BOTH the print statement AND the return value, which I don't believe is correct.

```
public class Task01
{
    // final dimensions of the paper
    private double dimensions;
    // width of the paper which is 8.5
    private double paperWidth;
    // length of the paper which is 11
    private double paperLength; 

    public Task01(){
        dimensions = 0;
        paperLength = 0;
        paperWidth = 0;
    }

    public double printDimensions()
    {
        final double LENGTH = 11; // inches
        final double WIDTH = 8.5; // inches
        final double MM_PER_INCH = 25.4; // millimeters per inch

        paperLength = LENGTH * MM_PER_INCH;
        paperWidth = WIDTH * MM_PER_INCH;


        System.out.printf("The dimension are: " + paperLength + " x " + paperWidth);

        return dimensions;
    }
}
```

For the tester, I have a seperate class that I use to call the methods I create by creating a new object for that task.

public class Tester
{

```
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        System.out.println("The task begins now: ");

        // creating a new object for the task
        Task01 task01 = new Task01();

        System.out.println(task01.printDimensions());
    }
}
```

Comment: So... if you don't want to return a value from your method, don't.  What's the problem?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?  The compiler is not allowing me to compile the program without adding a return value of some sort.

Comment: Because your method returns `double`. Change it to `void`. So it'd be `public void printDimensions()`

Comment: You should read [the oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) on defining methods.  Specifically #2 (the return type).

Comment: If I change it to void I won't be able to call it on the tester, which is part of the issue I have been running into.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to call it? What is your "tester"? Tell us what you're using and edit your post to show the relevant lines that call this method.

Comment: Okay, just change `System.out.println(task01.printDimensions());` to `task01.printDimensions();` Your issue is that `println()` can't accept `void` as an argument. You don't need that extra call anyway since your method already prints.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it.  That was all I needed to do, lol.  Kind of embarassing :(

Comment: No problem! We all started somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can remove the line `System.out.printf("The dimension are: " + paperLength + " x " + paperWidth);` from the `printDimensions` methods. Then your tester class just create an instance of `Task01` and call the method in a print statement which would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task01 t = new Task01();
    System.out.println(t.printDimensions);
}
```

The other option as already stated is to change the method type to `void` rather than `double` and remove the return statement. Then call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task01 t = new Task01();
    t.printDimensions();
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, that was my fix.  I appreciate it.  And to think that all I needed to do was just call the void method without the println.  Embarassing.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
public double printDimensions()
```

To this

```
public void printDimensions()
```

then remove the return statement at the end of that method

Comment: When I use `pubic void printDimensions()' I have trouble calling the method in my tester, because it's a void.  Even when I apply arguments to the void method it still will not allow me to call the method through my tester.

Comment: The method isn't `void`, it just has a `void` return type. Now you might be running into issues if you're trying to assign the result of a method with a `void` return type to a `double` variable.